# Do dark images have smaller size?

Tags: image, colors, image-compression

We know that different colors are formed using RGB components ranging between 0 and 255. The black color has (0,0,0) composition and white has (255,255,255) composition. Does that have any effect on image size? Are darker images smaller in size than brighter ones. I took two frames of equal dimension and colored them with black and white color. And I have noticed that black one has lesser size(Few kilobytes lesser). Here are the images:

Black Colored Image:

[image: Black Colored Image]

White Colored Image:

[image: White Colored Image]

If so what could be the possible reason behind this and Is it specific to image file extensions?

Comment: What is the format? Perhaps image compression has done something weird?

Comment: Mousing over the imgs shows they're pngs.

Comment: @Ben I think png is a lossless compression!

Comment: @AngadSingh Yes it is, but it is still compressed, which might lead to the images being different sizes ...

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to how the compression algorithm has dealt with the 2 images. `png` format should be lossless compression but it is still compressed. So if you do a diff on the 1 files you will see a small change in the header indicating they were created at different times. But the main change is in the binary data at the end of the file. This is where your big difference will be.

Things contributing to this might be perceived transparency and other effects. If you have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) you can see that not all pixels have the same cost to store. This is probably what is causing the image size difference.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer:
[https://cloudinary.com/blog/a_one_color_image_is_worth_two_thousand_words#:~:text=A%20fully%20transparent%20image%20gets,there's%20the%20extra%20alpha%20channel](https://cloudinary.com/blog/a_one_color_image_is_worth_two_thousand_words#:%7E:text=A%20fully%20transparent%20image%20gets,there%27s%20the%20extra%20alpha%20channel)).

Short answer:
[image]